# Django rest framework quickstart tutorial error The included URLconf 'tutorial.urls'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried to complete the drf quickstart tutorial from https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

using

Python 3.6.1

django-rest-framework 3.9.4

Django 2.2.1

but when I run

```
   python manage.py runserver
```

I got an error

```py
  File "E:\Dropbox\python\drf2\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'tutorial.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

project structure:

[image]

the content of tutorial/urls.py

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from tutorial.quickstart import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', views.GroupViewSet)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

Comment: And what is your `tutorial/urls.py`?

Comment: seems like you've missed [this portion of the tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#urls)

Comment: @Gasanov added to the post

Comment: @JPG I copy-pasted it from the tutorial as the last attempt to make it

Comment: @arpa if you want to follow that tutorial, your project structure is incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `quickstart` folder doesn't look at the [right location](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#project-setup). It should be at the same level as `settings.py`.

You can move the folder the `quickstart` to `drf2/tutorial/tutorial` and that would fix things.

NB, you likely missed the trailing dot in `django-admin startproject tutorial .`